# ローカル環境でrails sしたいのにできない。どうしたら良いですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rails s` でサーバーを立ち上げたいです。 ローカル環境にて`rails s`をしたら以下のエラーが出て

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:233:in `search_for': Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'executable-hooks (= 1.6.1)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:288:in `block in sort_dependencies'

from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:282:in each'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:282:in sort_by' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:282:in with_index'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:282:in sort_dependencies' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in block in sort_dependencies'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in with_no_such_dependency_error_handling' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in sort_dependencies'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in push_state_for_requirements' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:288:in push_initial_state'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:210:in start_resolution' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:168:in resolve'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in resolve' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:190:in resolve'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:411:in resolve' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:423:in resolve_current'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:230:in finish_resolve' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:287:in block in activate_bin_path'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:285:in synchronize' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:285:in activate_bin_path'         from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin/rails:25:in <main>' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in eval'         from       /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in <main>'.
```

#### 試したこと

gemファイルのsqlのバージョンを更新の記述をして `bundle install` したところ An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue. gem lockファイルを一旦削除して`bundle install`してAWS再起動、変わらなかったので復活させました。

PCはmac M1を使っていて、AWSを使ってプログラミングをしています。

読みずらいところがあるかもしれませんが 同じエラーが出たことがある方アドバイスお願いします。

Gemfile

```
    ruby '3.1.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.7', '>= 6.1.7.4'

gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'

gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'

gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false.  

    group :development, :test do
  
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end.  

    group :development do
 
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  
  gem 'spring'
end.   

    group :test do
  
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end.  

    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise'

gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

gem 'kaminari','~> 1.2.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'.  

   gem 'dotenv-rails'
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2' , '~> 0.5.5'
end.  

   gem 'active_storage_validations'

gem 'rails-i18n'

gem 'bootstrap4-kaminari-views'

gem "net-smtp"
gem "net-pop"
gem "net-imap"

gem 'shared-mime-info', '~> 0.2.5'.
```

Gemlockfile

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.7.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.7.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.7.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.7.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.7.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    active_storage_validations (1.0.4)
      activejob (>= 5.2.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.2.0)
      activestorage (>= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
    activerecord (6.1.7.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
    activestorage (6.1.7.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.7.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.4)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.19)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.16.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    bootstrap4-kaminari-views (1.0.1)
      kaminari (>= 0.13)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.39.2)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    crass (1.0.6)
    date (3.3.3)
    devise (4.9.2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    dotenv (2.8.1)
    dotenv-rails (2.8.1)
      dotenv (= 2.8.1)
      railties (>= 3.2)
    erubi (1.12.0)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    globalid (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.14.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.12.2)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.17, < 3)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.6.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    kaminari (1.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.2)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.2)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-core (1.2.2)
    listen (3.8.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.21.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    mail (2.8.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_magick (4.12.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.18.1)
    msgpack (1.7.2)
    mysql2 (0.5.5)
    net-imap (0.3.6)
      date
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.1)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.9)
    nokogiri (1.15.3-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    public_suffix (5.0.3)
    puma (3.12.6)
    racc (1.7.1)
    rack (2.2.7)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.4)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.7.6)
      rack
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (6.1.7.4)
      actioncable (= 6.1.7.4)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.7.4)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.7.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.4)
      actiontext (= 6.1.7.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.7.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      minitest
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
      loofah (~> 2.21)
      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
    rails-i18n (7.0.7)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      railties (>= 6.0.0, < 8)
    railties (6.1.7.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.8.1)
    responders (3.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      railties (>= 5.2)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    ruby-vips (2.1.4)
      ffi (~> 1.12)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt

    selenium-webdriver (4.10.0)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    spring (4.1.1)
    sprockets (4.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.6.3-x86_64-linux)
    thor (1.2.2)
    tilt (2.2.0)
    timeout (0.4.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (5.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
    webpacker (5.4.4)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket (1.2.9)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.6.8)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  active_storage_validations
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  bootstrap4-kaminari-views
  byebug
  capybara (>= 3.26)
  devise
  dotenv-rails
  image_processing (~> 1.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  jquery-rails
  kaminari (~> 1.2.1)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  mysql2
  net-imap
  net-pop
  net-smtp
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rack-mini-profiler (~> 2.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.7, >= 6.1.7.4)
  rails-i18n
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver (>= 4.0.0.rc1)
  spring
  sqlite3 (~> 1.4)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 5.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.19
```

以下　bundle installを実行した結果です。

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies.........
Using rake 13.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.2.2
Using i18n 1.14.1
Using minitest 5.20.0
Using tzinfo 2.0.6
Using zeitwerk 2.6.12
Using activesupport 6.1.7.6
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.12.0
Using racc 1.7.3
Fetching nokogiri 1.15.5 (x86_64-linux)
Installing nokogiri 1.15.5 (x86_64-linux)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.2.0
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.22.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.6.0
Using actionview 6.1.7.6
Using rack 2.2.8
Using rack-test 2.1.0
Using actionpack 6.1.7.6
Fetching nio4r 2.6.1
Installing nio4r 2.6.1 with native extensions
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.6
Using actioncable 6.1.7.6
Using globalid 1.2.1
Using activejob 6.1.7.6
Using activemodel 6.1.7.6
Using activerecord 6.1.7.6
Using marcel 1.0.2
Using mini_mime 1.1.5
Using activestorage 6.1.7.6
Using date 3.3.4
Using timeout 0.4.1
Using net-protocol 0.2.2
Fetching net-imap 0.4.7
Installing net-imap 0.4.7
Using net-pop 0.1.2
Using net-smtp 0.4.0
Using mail 2.8.1
Using actionmailbox 6.1.7.6
Using actionmailer 6.1.7.6
Using actiontext 6.1.7.6
Fetching active_storage_validations 1.1.3
Installing active_storage_validations 1.1.3
Fetching bcrypt 3.1.20
Installing bcrypt 3.1.20 with native extensions
Using msgpack 1.7.2
Using bootsnap 1.17.0
Using kaminari-core 1.2.2
Using kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
Using kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
Using kaminari 1.2.2
Using bundler 2.3.19
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using thor 1.3.0
Using railties 6.1.7.6
Using sprockets 4.2.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.4.2
Using rails 6.1.7.6
Using bootstrap4-kaminari-views 1.0.1
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 3.1.1
Using warden 1.2.9
Using devise 4.9.3
Using dotenv 2.8.1
Using dotenv-rails 2.8.1
Using ffi 1.16.3
Using mini_magick 4.12.0
Using ruby-vips 2.2.0
Using image_processing 1.12.2
Using jbuilder 2.11.5
Using jquery-rails 4.6.0
Installing mysql2 0.5.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/ec2-user/environment/tabimaru_portfolio/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby -I
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
./siteconf20231130-8219-zq4k8m.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-openssl-dir
        --without-openssl-dir
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysqlclient-dir
        --without-mysqlclient-dir
        --with-mysqlclient-include
        --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
        --with-mysqlclient-lib
        --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in `block in
find_library': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    paths = paths.flat_map {|path| path.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)}
                                       ^^^^^^
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in
`each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in
`flat_map'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in
`find_library'
        from extconf.rb:131:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/home/ec2-user/environment/tabimaru_portfolio/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/ec2-user/environment/tabimaru_portfolio/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5
for inspection.
Results logged to
/home/ec2-user/environment/tabimaru_portfolio/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/mysql2-0.5.5/gem_make.out

/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in
`block in build'
  /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in
`build'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in
`build_extension'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in
`block in build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in
`each'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in
`build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in
`build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:207:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
`do_install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:171:in
`install_serially'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:97:in
`call'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:71:in
`call'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer.rb:259:in
`install_in_parallel'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer.rb:209:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer.rb:89:in
`block in run'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in
`block in lock'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in
`open'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in
`lock'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer.rb:71:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/installer.rb:23:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:255:in
`block in install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/settings.rb:132:in
`temporary'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:254:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
`invoke_command'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in
`dispatch'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in
`dispatch'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in
`start'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in
`start'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/exe/bundle:48:in
`block in <top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in
`with_friendly_errors'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.19/exe/bundle:36:in `<top
(required)>'
  /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
  /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

Comment: 「ローカルで」と言いつつ、エラーメッセージに出ているのは AWS 環境に見えます (AWS はローカルではなくクラウドです)。

Comment: `bundle install`の実行結果はどうなりますか？実行結果全てを質問に貼り付けてください。

Comment: 本番のサーバーで立ち上げた時はちゃんと動いているのですが、aws上でrails sで動かそうとするとできなくてgit hubには変更をpushできる状態です。

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [mysql2 gemのインストールエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/95759/mysql2-gem%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc)