# railsのデプロイ時mysql2 gemのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, rubygems, gemfile

**解決したいこと**
今Railsのアプリをmysql2を使用しデプロイしようとしたのですが、

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/ruby -I
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20231211-19703-1jgj6jw.rb extconf.rb
--with-mysql-config\=/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... no
-----
Using mysql_config at
/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. 
You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-openssl-dir
    --without-openssl-dir
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
extconf.rb:118:in ``': Permission denied -
/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
(Errno::EACCES)
    from extconf.rb:118:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
which can be found here:

/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.5.5/gem_make.out

/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:99:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:48:in
`block in build'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tempfile.rb:291:in
`open'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:30:in
`build'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:169:in
`block in build_extension'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in
`synchronize'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in
`build_extension'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in
`block in build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in
`each'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in
`build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/installer.rb:844:in
`build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:198:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in
`do_install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:141:in
`install_serially'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:91:in
`call'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:67:in
`call'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:244:in
`install_in_parallel'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:201:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:89:in
`block in run'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in
`block in lock'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in
`open'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in
`lock'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:71:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:23:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:261:in
`block in install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/settings.rb:131:in
`temporary'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:260:in
`install'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
`run'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
`invoke_command'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in
`dispatch'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in
`dispatch'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in
`start'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in
`start'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/exe/bundle:45:in
`block in <top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in
`with_friendly_errors'
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.12/exe/bundle:33:in
`<top (required)>'
  /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and
Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

というエラーが出てしまいました。
自分的に読み解いた感じ、

```
(Errno::EACCES)
    from extconf.rb:118:in `<main>'
```

と書いてあったので、

```
ver = `#{mc} --version`.chomp.to_f #extconf.rbの118行目
```

を確認したのですが、知見が足りず理解できませんでした。

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
which can be found here:

/var/www/rails/origin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log
```

とも書いてあったので、mkmf.logへ行ってみたのですがどこをみればいいのかわかりませんでした。

**ここで質問なのですが**
今回はどのようなエラーなのかと解決策をご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: Ruby や Rails は詳しくないですが、 `Permission denied` が出ているのでアクセス権限周りの問題な可能性があります。(Ruby は rbenv を使っているのに gem がシステムのものを参照して書き込みに失敗している？) / エラーが出るまでに実行したコマンドや、実行環境に関する情報 (各ツールのバージョン等) を追記しておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: 過去の類似質問 [mysql2 gemのインストールエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/95759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーの原因は`mysql_config`、`mysql_config5`、`mariadb_config`のいずれも見つからないからです。extcnof.rbの流れとしては、ローカル変数`mc`が`nil`になり、`#{mc} --version`が `--version`となって、この文字列をシェルで実行しようとするため、そのような実行ファイルはないとしてエラーになります。

解決には、mysql2にはMySQLまたはMariaDBの開発パッケージ(ライブラリとヘッダー)が必要です。[mysql2のREADME](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/tree/0.5.5#installing)を参考に、お使いのOSにあわせてインストールしてください。

Comment: MySQLはしてたのですが、ruby-develもインストールしなければrailsにて使えないんですね。よってruby-develをインストールしたのちにbundle instalを実行した結果できました。